# Remove all added classes to body tag

Tags: 6, theming

How do I remove all the classes that are being added to the body tag? Currently my body tag is :

```
<body>
```

This however is rendered as

```
<body class="lightbox-processed admin-nw admin-vertical admin-df">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are added there via Javascript of the Lightbox and Admin Menu modules. You can either disable those modules or modify/override their Javascript. You could also use custom Javascript to remove the classes from the body element. Anyway, the question is, why would you want to remove the classes?